# DATABASE: I need to redo this query but without using JOIN. I need to use subquery

Tags: sql

```
SELECT countries.name AS CountryName, COUNT(DISTINCT airlines.id)AS DistinctAirlinesCount 
FROM routes
JOIN airports ON routes.destination_airport_id = airports.id
JOIN airlines ON routes.airline_id = airlines.id
JOIN countries ON airports.country_id = countries.id
WHERE countries.name IN('France', 'Germany', 'Spain', 'Italy')
GROUP BY countries.name;
```

I redo it:

```
SELECT countries.name AS CountryName, COUNT(DISTINCT airlines.id) AS DistinctAirlinesCount 
FROM routes
WHERE destination_airport_id IN (
    SELECT airports.id
    FROM airports
    WHERE airports.country_id IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM countries
        WHERE countries.name IN ('France', 'Germany', 'Spain', 'Italy')
    )
)
GROUP BY countries.name;
```

Then it shows this output:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "countries"
LINE 1: SELECT countries.name AS CountryName, COUNT(DISTINCT
```

I don't know how to join multiple table without using JOIN

I expect the output to Provide a query that displays the how many different airlines operate routes that end at airports (destination) in the countries of France, Germany, Spain and Italy. I must display the distinct count of airlines and the name of the country display the distinct count of airlines and the name of the country

Comment: Read 'variable subtitution' :[https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST]

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags. Please add the one back that you actually use!

Comment: Well yes, you are referencing `countries` but only select `from routes` so why would you not expect an error? A subquery can correlate to the outer scope but not vice-versa. You would need to select `from countries` - it doesn't matter what table you start from as inner joins are commutative

Comment: why do you want to avoid joins, have you compared the query plans with and without? also you can use a subquery in from if you absolutely want to